# How to use an XML file uploaded by the user?

Tags: jquery, xml, file-upload

I want the user to be able to upload an XML file (using `<input type="file">`). Let's say this file is:

```xml
<fruit>Watermelon</fruit>
<fruit>Banana</fruit>
```

After the user uploads this file, the program will use the informations in the XML (in this case, the fruits). Is that possible? Note: I'm a beginner. If you can, please explain me in details. I don't know how to access uploaded files.

I am using jQuery in this project. If there is not a solution to this problem with jQuery, please tell me what language should I use.

Comment: That isn't an XML file. XML files are allowed only one root element.

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is a client side library.jQuery executes in your client browser.

You can upload the file and process that in any Server side language like PHP/ASP.NET etc.... You can do any kind of operation (Save the file to disk/ Read the content etc..) to this file on your server side.

Your page should have some markup like this to have the file upload control. Your enctype value should be `multipart/form-data` to send the file to the server page.

```
<form  action="myServerpage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="someId" name="someName">
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[Here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php/) is a PHP sample and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) is an ASP.NET sample.

There are some client side asynchronous file upload solutions like uplodify, but even with that, you need a server page to process the request from client.

As icktoofay mentioned, HTML5 too handle it at the client side

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to read files selected in an `input`.

Say you had your `file` input in a variable named `fileSelector`. First, you would get the files selected by using the `files` property of it. Assuming it only takes one file, you could probably just choose the first one.

Then, construct a [`FileReader`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader). Set [its `onload` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-onload) to a callback for when the file read has been completed. Call [`readAsText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsText) with the file and encoding. Once your callback has been called, use [the `result` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-result) of the `FileReader`.

Then parse that XML and use it as desired.